# I want to search no of rows containing aphostrophe string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to search no of rows containing "'" aphostrophe string in a particular field. I
tried with

```
select * from table where field like "%samad's%"
```

i get only 0 counts. but I am sure that exists in many rows.

how to query them and help are definitely appriciated

Comment: why are you doing `string's` not `'`?

Comment: single quotes for sql strings, so double up inside for an apostrophe

Comment: hey all i have an entry in my database like this samad's then how to search this string

Comment: Er, waitasec.  You want NO rows?  That is, you want to search for rows that do not contain an apostrophe?  Or do you want the *number* of rows, as suggested by `count(*)`?

Comment: basically i have used mysql_real_escape_string for insertion so value saved in my db like this samad\'s the Q is how to search this string with like clause

Comment: i have found my Query solution

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(addslashes($search))); to search no of rows with aphostrophe string like this samad's

Comment: @ghoti, Samad meant to write "no.", the abbreviation for "number" (*numero*), rather than "no".  "No." can be a bit ambiguous without that period, no?  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%''%'
```

Comment: i have an entry in my database like this samad's then how to search this string ....

Comment: `where field like 'samad''s'` -- is that what you mean?

Comment: basically i have used mysql_real_escape_string for insertion so  value saved in my db like this samad\'s the Q is how to search this string with like clause

Comment: @Samad, though, internally, escaped strings are stored with an escape character, the escaped characters won't be returned in the results. You don't have to unescape.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%\\''%'
```

Comment: did you mean for the backslash to be there?

Comment: @dldnh: Yes - in fact, it should have been a double-backslash (now corrected) - see this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736128/how-to-check-apostrophe-with-where-clause-using-mysql/9736183

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the same method again......What i meant is

```
<?php    
    $valToSrch = mysql_real_escape_string("'");
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE "%$valToSrch%"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware: sometimes, if people cut and paste content from a word processor into a form, your single-quote apostrophes may actually be a [right single quotation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).  If that's the case, you'll need to expand your search, depending on how that character was encoded for inclusion in the database.

Multiple others have posted solutions for you to match single ticks.  Replace `*` with `COUNT(*)` in any of them to get the "number" of matches.

If you need to include unicode support, show us the structure of the table, so we know what we're dealing with.

```
mysqldump -d dbname tablename
```

(we don't need the comments from `mysqldump`'s output, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

> basically i have used mysql_real_escape_string for insertion so value saved in my db like this samad\'s

value IS NOT saved in your db like this `samad\'s`. it is saved as `samad's`
you have to verify it first.
if it's indeed contains extra backslash, that means you are escaping your data twice. 
you have to fix your code to get rid of double escaping in this case and clean your data already entered in the db.

once you done with it, you'll be able to find an apostrophe with trivial

```
select * from table where field like "%samad\'s%"
```

query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution to check this string `samad/'s` in database with like clause

```
<?php 
$search = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(addslashes($search)));
?>

select * from table where field like '".$search."'
```

Thanx for everyone to share your answer with me

Answer (score -1):

just use this...It will help you

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE "%'%"
```

Comment: basically i have used mysql_real_escape_string for insertion so value saved in my db like this samad\'s the Q is how to search this string with like clause

Comment: @Samad - your question says `rows containing "'" aphostrophe string`.  A string is one or more characters.  An apostrophe is both a character, and a single-character string.